# Regex in Java to only allow digits and points

Tags: java, regex, validation

I'm struggling with a TextField limitation, where it shall only be possible to enter digits divided by points. Here is what I got:

```
 public static void allowOnlyNumbersAndPoints(final TextField tf) {
        tf.textProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(final ObservableValue<? extends String> ov, final String oldValue, final String newValue) {
                if (!newValue.matches("\\d+(\\.\\d+)*$")) {
                    tf.setText(newValue.replaceAll("[^\\d]", ""));
                }
            }
        });

    }
```

How do I replace the dots with "" as well?

THANKS :)

Comment: Usually it’s better to [use a TextFormatter](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/14/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/TextInputControl.html#setTextFormatter%28javafx.scene.control.TextFormatter%29) instead, so you don’t inhibit the user’s ability to edit.  And as a bonus, you won’t have to assume that `.` is the decimal separator (since in many locales, it isn’t).  For example, `tf.setTextFormatter(new TextFormatter<Number>(new NumberStringConverter()));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `\\d+\\.?\\d*`.

**Demo:**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] testStrs = { "100", "123.23", "a1", "1a", "a1.2", "0.23" };
        for (String s : testStrs) {
            System.out.println(s + (s.matches("\\d+\\.?\\d*") ? " matches " : " doesn't match"));
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
100 matches 
123.23 matches 
a1 doesn't match
1a doesn't match
a1.2 doesn't match
0.23 matches
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use the regex `"[^0-9]"` in your call to `replaceAll` to replace anything that isn't a digit. `"[^\\d]"` (which you currently have) shouldn't work, as named groups don't work inside square brackets.

Answer (score 0):

This might work `\d+[\d.]*[\d$]*`

Did you mean points as in many points or only one point?

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this.

```
String r = "(?:\\d+)?[\\.]?\\d+|\\d+\\.";

for (String num : new String[] { "2.33", "33.3", "33", ".33",
        "44.", "4.4.4", "a.3", "44.k" }) {
    System.out.printf("%5s : %s%n", num,
            " " + (num.matches(r) ? "valid" : "not valid"));

}
```

Prints

```
 2.33 :  valid
 33.3 :  valid
   33 :  valid
  .33 :  valid
  44. :  valid
4.4.4 :  not valid
  a.3 :  not valid
 44.k :  not valid
```